# Show local hour in php on WP content page

Tags: php, wordpress, date, hour

i'm using this function to show hour on a wp page (by function.php)

```
function displaydate(){
return date('H:i');
}
```

But it retourns me server hour.

I want it to display me the Europe/Paris hour.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

use `date_default_timezone_set` to set the time zone:

```
function displaydate(){
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');
    return date('H:i');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using the `DateTime` class as an alternative to `date()` once you begin adding complexity such as changing the timezone.

Example:

```
function displaydate() {
    $datetime = new DateTime;
    $paris_tz = new DateTimeZone( 'Europe/Paris' );

    $datetime->setTimezone( $paris_tz );

    return $datetime->format( 'H:i' );
}
```

Further reading: http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php